# Navigation bar gets taller when using a dropdown (only on mobile)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navigationbar

While working in bootstrap, I'm trying to do a horizontal top navigation bar with a back button on the left and a dropdown with user preference and logout in the right.

So far my code is like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-left">
        <li><a href="javascript: history.go(-1)"> &lt; Back</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">

      <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
          Usuario <span class="caret"></span>
          </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu">
              <li><a href="/user">User</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="{{logout_url}}">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>

</nav>
```

Which works perfectly on desktop, but when I'm doing the browsing in a phone, the behavior change, and makes the navbar taller.

Anyone has an idea why?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The navbar includes the dropdown within it on a mobile, that's the bootstrap way. If you don't want this behavior then you will have to change some css. Find the below in the bootstrap.css and comment out as below or delete. You will then have the desktop behavior

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
    .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
    /* position: static; */
    /* float: none; */
    /* width: auto; */
    /* margin-top: 0; */
    /* background-color: transparent; */
    /* border: 0; */
    /* -webkit-box-shadow: none; */
    /* box-shadow: none; */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are using the `collapse` feature of bootstrap properly. You forgot about the toggle navigation section. You should include the `<div class="navbar-header">` section even if you don't want to show the "brand" as that section includes the collapsing menu in the mobile version. Here is the code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Delicious</a> <!--delete this line if you don't want a brand-->
    </div>
   <!-- your menu goes here-->
  </div>
</nav>
```

I know this isn't exactly the problem, but I've found that bootstrap can break in weird ways when you don't call all the parts. So try this. Bootstrap's Dropdown isn't really meant for mobile anyway.